# General expression for exponentiating a matrix?

Tags: matrices

$A= \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos(x) & \sin(x) \\
        -\sin(x) & \cos(x) \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

I found that

$A^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x) & 2\cos(x)\sin(x) \\
        -2\cos(x)\sin(x) & \cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x) \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

$A^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos(2x) & \sin(2x) \\
        -\sin(2x) & \cos(2x) \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

and

$A^3 = \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos^2(x)[\cos^2(x)-3\sin^2(x)] & \sin(x)[3\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x)] \\
        -\sin(x)[3\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)] & \cos(x)[-3\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)] \\
        \end{pmatrix}$
$A^3 = \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos(2x)cos(x) - \sin(x)\sin(2x) & \sin(x)\cos(2x) + \cos(x)\sin(2x) \\
        -\cos(x)sin(2x)-\sin(x)\cos(2x) &  \cos(x) + \cos(2x) -\sin(x)\sin(2x) \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

but I am unable to find a general solution. I probably need to perform some algebraic manipulations or whatnot.

Comment: Try using trig identities; e.g. For the (1,1) entry: $\cos(2x)\cos(x)-\sin(2x)\sin(x)=\cos(3x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, following formula holds: (Proof of this formula uses induction.)
$$A^n =\begin{pmatrix}
\cos (nx) & -\sin(nx) \\
\sin(nx) & \cos(nx) 
\end{pmatrix}$$

In fact, matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
\cos (x) & -\sin(x) \\
\sin(x) & \cos(x) 
\end{pmatrix}$ behave similar to $\cos x + i \sin x$.

Comment: do you know how to transform A^3 to the 3x form?

Comment: @wonton You can use the angle addition identities for sine and cosine applied to the last formula in your question. The more fundamental reason is the one Alex Yocuis mentioned however; the matrix behaves this way because applying a rotation of angle $x$ a total of $n$ times is the same as applying a single rotation of $nx$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this is rotation by the angle x